# How do I modify all the list elements as patterns

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

Is there any easier way to change all the list elements as elements with patterns?

Here is an example:

```
list={a,b,c,d}
```

I want to transform it as a list of patterns as:

```
{a_,b_,c_,d_}
```

Comment: Something like `Pattern[#, _] & /@ {a, b, c, d}`?

Comment: Yes, of course. I was stupidly trying substitution `/. {x_ -> HoldForm[Pattern[x, Blank[]]]}`.

Comment: Well, taking the replacement route would need `Replace[]` and not `ReplaceAll[]`, for reasons that should be clear after some thought: `Replace[{a, b, c, d}, x_ :> Pattern @@ {x, _}, 1]`. If you've figured out why, I encourage you to write an answer to your question.